# Subset a Dataframe Based on Column Value

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I am processing a number of dataframes using for loops. In each one of these dataframes, there is a variable called `utc` that can either be a 0, 1, 2, or 3. If `utc` is a 1, then I need to subset rows 2:8. If `utc` is a 2, then I need to subset rows 3:9 (and so on). The variable `utc` is a constant number in each separate dataframe.

Reproducible Data:

```
structure(list(lai_lv = c(3.6352286643901, 3.64098631754469, 
3.64098631754469, 3.64098631754469, 3.64098631754469, 3.64098631754469, 
3.64098631754469, 3.64098631754469, 3.64098631754469, 3.64098631754469
), lai_hv = c(2.43529312827423, 2.43624785398554, 2.43624785398554, 
2.43624785398554, 2.43624785398554, 2.43624785398554, 2.43624785398554, 
2.43624785398554, 2.43624785398554, 2.43624785398554), d2m = c(298.379793852221, 
298.353981989364, 298.351944210717, 298.305754561395, 298.217450820042, 
298.238507866057, 298.326811607409, 298.34447235568, 297.835706953582, 
297.798347678394), utc = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried to use `case_when` to accomplish this task:

```
case_when(data$utc == 1 ~ slice(data, 2:8))
```

But the following error occurred:

```
Error in `case_when()`:
! Can't recycle `..1 (left)` (size 10) to match `..1 (right)` (size 7).
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you always selecting the same number of rows? Would something like `slice(data, (first(utc)+1):(first(utc)+7))` work? You have just one data.frame in this example so it's not clear how this needs to work when you have more than one.

Comment: try `lapply(manydata, function(X) slice(X, (first(utc)+1):min(nrow(X), (first(utc)+7))))`

Comment: @MrFlick your code works, however I'm trying to make it applicable to all of my datasets. My actual dataframe is 48 rows x 550 columns. Each one of the 48 rows represents an hour of data. If the UTC = 1, I need to subset rows 2:25. If the UTC = 2, I need to subset rows 3:26 (and so on). Each dataframe (~500 dataframes or so) has a specific UTC attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this, unless I'm not mistaken:

```
df[(df$utc[1]+1):(df$utc[1]+24),]
```

When
`df$utc[1]` = 1, it goes from rows 2 to 25, and so on.

If there are many dataframes, you can do this:

```
dfs <- list(df) # put all of the dataframes in here

map(dfs, ~ .x[(.x$utc[1]+1):(.x$utc[1]+24),])
```

Comment: Thank you! This works and is much more "elegant" than the solution I came up with the meantime. I appreciate it.